# Recursive directory scan using boost file system

Tags: c++, boost

I have written the following code for searching and recursive directory.

Please review it.

Can it be optimized to avoid traversing symlink and handle "abort" signal inside for loop to continue the flow

```
void Dirs::scan_dir(string dir_name, DataBase &b, string owner) {
    fs::path p(dir_name);
    if (!fs::exists(p)) {
        std::cout<<"Path does not exist"<<std::endl;
        return;
    }
    if(fs::is_directory(p)) {
        fs::recursive_directory_iterator end_iter;
        std::vector<std::string> check_link;
        for(fs::recursive_directory_iterator begin(p); begin != end_iter; ++begin){
            try {
                fs::path tmp = begin->path().filename();
                string f_path = begin->path().relative_path().string();
                f_path = "/" + f_path;
                bool link_found = false;
                for(std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = check_link.begin();
                        it != check_link.end(); ++it) {
                    if (f_path.find(*it) != std::string::npos){
                        link_found = true;
                        std::cout<<"link name"<<*it<<" in path is  "<<f_path<<std::endl;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(link_found)
                    continue;
                if(fs::is_symlink(begin->path())) {
                    check_link.push_back(begin->path().filename());
                    continue;
                }

                if(fs::is_regular_file(begin->path())) {
                    std::vector<std::string> ls_file_output = this->getfiledetail(f_path);
                    string f_time = std::to_string(fs::last_write_time(begin->path()));
#if 1
                    b.insert_disk_analyze_query(ls_file_output[2], 
                                            this->local_time(), 
                                            tmp.string(),
                                            f_path,
                                            ls_file_output[3],
                                            f_time);
#endif
                }
            }
            catch(fs::filesystem_error &ex) {
                std::cout<<" File.."<<ex.what()<<std::endl;
                signal(SIGINT, signal_callback_handler);
            }
            catch(const std::exception &ex) {
                std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
            }
            catch(...) {
                std::cout<<"unkown error"<<std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```